# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ambiguous object code,name>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<intermediary>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am doing a query with IEnumerable and it seems I don't understand why I'm wrong.
I want to return certain columns from my table. But something is wrong.

```
    public class Intermediary
   {
   public string CODE { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   }

   public async Task<IEnumerable<Intermediary>> GetTest(string company)
   {
    var db = new SibaCiidDbContext();
    var results = (from o in db.Intermediary 
                   where o.CompanyCode == company 
                   select o).Select(o => new 
                   {
                       CODE = o.CompanyCode,
                       NAME = o.FullName
                   });

    return await Task.FromResult(results.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Something is wrong, but we cannot guess what, you need to tell us what doesn't work. Also, what do you expect `await Task.FromResult(result)` to do?

Comment: I think the problem is that you aren't returning IEnumerable<Intermediary> you are returning IEnumerable<object> because you are creating an anonymous type in your query and an anonymous type can only be cast to object.

Comment: [I downvoted because your problem statement is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Comment: Maybe `Select(o => new Intermediary
                   {
                       CODE = o.CompanyCode,
                       NAME = o.FullName
                   }` helps. (I added the type name `Intermediary`)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes is close, it would be... new Intermediary { CompanyCode = o.CompanyCode, FullName = o.FullName }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework has some async methods. You should use ToListAsync() but your method has to return the complete object. When you receive the object returned by the method, then you can use the Select  method to get what you want.

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<Intermediary>> GetTest(string company)
{

    var db = new SibaCiidDbContext();
    var results = (from o in db.Intermediary where o.CompanyCode == company select o);

    return await results.ToListAsync();
}
```

So after this you can use it like this

```
List<Intermediary> objectList = await object.GetTest(nameCompany);
var anotherList = objectList.Select(o => new {
    CODE = o.CompanyCode,
    NAME = o.FullName
});
```

if you want to return just these properties, then you might create an object with these properties. For example:

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public string CODE { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

     public async Task<IEnumerable<SomeObject>> GetTest(string company)
{

    var db = new SibaCiidDbContext();
    var results = (from o in db.Intermediary where o.CompanyCode == company select new SomeObject{CODE = o.CompanyCode, NAME = o.FullName });

    return await results.ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming your database table is the same as the class name (Intermediary) and using System.Linq; and 
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Intermediary>> GetTest(string company)
    {
        using (var context = new SibaCiidDbContext())
        {
            return
                await context.Intermediary
                        .Where(query => query.CompanyCode == company)
                        .Select(result =>
                new Intermediary
                {
                    CODE = result.CompanyCode,
                    NAME = result.FullName
                })
                .ToListAsync();


        }
    }
```